# How to return a JavaScript function in a <p> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a separate JavaScript file and I want to return the results of a function in a `<p>` tag. For example, in my js file I have:

```
var i=0;
function add(num) {
    return i+=num;
}
```

How would I use that in a `<p>` tag in my HTML file? So if the function returned 5, the web page would show 5 where I placed the `<p>` tag.

Comment: [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML)

Comment: Or, *preferably*, [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) (W3, standards-compliant) or [`innerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899(v=vs.85).aspx) (IE, though implemented in some other browsers for compatibility).

Comment: The guys new to SO and you're going to downvote him, possibly causing him to be banned from asking in the future?!

Answer (score 3):

Separate your HTML from your JavaScript.  Don't think of the JavaScript as "in a `<p>` tag" because that's not really how JavaScript works.  Instead, have some way to identify that `<p>` element and use JavaScript to target that element and set its content.  For example, you might have this in your HTML:

```
<p id="target"></p>
```

Then in your JavaScript (likely at the end of the page), you'd have something like this:

```
document.getElementById('target').textContent = 'some value';
```

So if your value is `i` then:

```
document.getElementById('target').textContent = i;
```

Comment: That was what I was doing previously but I was just wondering if it was simply possible to use a variable from my JS file rather than set it within the JS file.

Comment: @HaydenPerry: In a way, yes.  But not in the way you think.  At least, not *cleanly*.  If you're looking to simply *bind* your HTML elements to JavaScript values then you might look into a framework like AngularJS for example.  It allows you to define and build your models in JavaScript and then use some template-like syntax in your HTML to automatically place values from the JavaScript models.  It's overkill for an example as simple as this one, but very useful for larger and more complex examples.

Comment: Oh okay - I'll just stick to innerHTML then. I was only wondering if it was possible to fetch a variable rather than having to set the element with innerHTML. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

**1) Dynamic:** If the value changes after the page has loaded, then use something like this:

```js
function doCalc(nr) {
  // get current value of <p> and parse it to an integer
  var current_nr = parseInt(document.getElementById("result").innerHTML);
  
  // add nr to current_nr and place back in the <p>
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (current_nr+nr);  
}
```

```html
<p id="result">0</p>
<input type="button" value="+ 1" onclick="doCalc(1);" />
<input type="button" value="- 1" onclick="doCalc(-1);" />
<input type="button" value="+ 10" onclick="doCalc(10);" />
<input type="button" value="- 10" onclick="doCalc(-10);" />
```

**2) Static:** Otherwise, if you just want to print out the value in the page once when loading, use this:

The first code has to go in the `<head>` section of the page:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var the_variable = 0;

  function something(nr) {
    the_variable += nr;
  }

  something(2);
</script>
```

The second code goes into the `<body>` section of the page (where it is printed once, on load):

```html
<p><script type="text/javascript">document.write(the_variable);</script></p>
```